# a function with too many parameters in perl

Tags: perl

I have a function has too many parameters. I have viewed the resolving approach in PHP that passing class object into the function instead of many parameters. Is it any approaches for perl?

Thanks

Comment: Can you not explain a little better what you have and what you are doing?  Sure, you can "bundle" parameters into various data structures, or an object, but there are quite a few ways to do that (or something yet else).  The question is just too broad as it stands, I suggest you edit it to explain nicely what you have/need.

Comment: I feel a function with too many parameters is not easy to read and use.

Comment: OK. But there are many ways to organize that -- and how to do it well depends a lot on details of what your function does and what those parameters are.  Put them in array or a hash?  Or a hash with arrayrefs, to group different kinds of parameters?  Or perhaps a class?  Or maybe the program should be re-organized, and then there won't be so many loose parameters (but there would be a few objects instead)?

Comment: It's great that you are asking a question like this, as a good interface to a function is very important.  But there are many ways to approach that in general and more detail in the question would be very helpful for more specific and effective suggestions.

Comment: my function is to get values like name, age, ... and search the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem - as you know, if you want to do basic ordered parameters, perl's got that already.

However, sometimes you want something a little neater - you can pass a hash instead.

```
use Data::Dumper; 

sub myspecial {

  my %parameters = ( size => $default_size,
                     toggle => 1, 
                     @_ ); 

  print Dumper \%parameters;
}
```

Then you can call the subroutine as parameters:

```
myspecial ( size => 42, cabbage => "green" );
```

Because the 'size' parameter is defined within the sub, but `@_` is added to the end of the hash declaration, any size passed in will override the default.

And in this way, you can give named parameters in any order.

But there's always multiple ways to tackle this - sometimes you'll want to pass in a reference to a hash or object instead.

Comment: A named parameters list with default values, this is what I want. Thanks @sobrique

Answer (score 1):

you question is without any specifics -- too broad to answer in details.

Probably something like following piece of code should cover your requiremensts

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use feature 'say';

my $debug = 0;
my %hash;

my @fields = qw( first last age speciality phone email address );

while( <DATA> ) {
    @hash{@fields} = split ':';
    say Dumper(\%hash) if $debug;
    details(\%hash);
}

sub details {
    my $data = shift;

    foreach my $field (@fields) {
        printf "%-15s : %s\n", $field, $data->{$field};
    }
}

__DATA__
John:Smith:35:Web Developer:(1) 641-723-3472:john.smith@inter.net:2241-2832 Moon crescent, 50003 Iova, US 
Alice:Gomer:28:Accountant:(1) 641-723-7391:alice.gomer@inter.net:2241-630 Jupiter drive, 50006 Iova, US
```

output

```
first           : John
last            : Smith
age             : 35
speciality      : Web Developer
phone           : (1) 641-723-3472
email           : john.smith@inter.net
address         : 2241-2832 Moon crescent, 50003 Iova, US

first           : Alice
last            : Gomer
age             : 28
speciality      : Accountant
phone           : (1) 641-723-7391
email           : alice.gomer@inter.net
address         : 2241-630 Jupiter drive, 50006 Iova, US
```